# How to instantiate GameObject from prefab using Resources.Load?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I get a **NullReferenceException** error when I try to instantiate a GameObject the following way:

```
Side1_Slots.sGameObject[i] = Instantiate(Resources.Load<GameObject>(Side1_Slots.SlotAlliedPrefab), 
            Side1_Slots.SlotPosition[i], Quaternion.identity, UIContainer.transform);
```

Using this overloaded method for Instantiate:

```
Instantiate(GameObject Original, Vector3 position, Quaternion rotation, Transform parent);
```

Where:

```
Side1_Slots.SlotAlliedPrefab = "Prefabs/Battle/SlotAlliedPrefab";
```

I've tried the following project folder structures:

```
// Leads to NullReferenceException error
Resources/Prefabs/Battle/SlotAlliedPrefab
```

and:

```
//Leads to "Object you want to instantiate is null"
Prefabs/Battle/SlotAlliedPrefab
```

Which one is correct by the way? Google shows both ways, so I'm not sure...

Comment: Your first try should have worked. The prefab needs to be in a Resources folder and the string you pass into `Resources.Load(...)` is a path relative to the Resource folder. You might want to try without any subfolders to see if its a path issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need `Resources` in resource paths. `Prefabs/Battle/SlotAlliedPrefab` should do the job, provided it's the correct path to the asset. First, double-check your paths. Then, use the non-generic `Resources.Load()` to load the resource, then check its type (preferably with a debugger, use VSTS if you don't already). You may not have the correct asset type at that path. If `Resources.Load()` returns null, you probably have the wrong path, maybe a typo.

---

EDIT: You must store you asset in a Resources folder. But the path you pass to `Resources.Load` will be relative to the root of the closest Resources folder. For example, if you have an asset at:

`Assets\MyGame\Models\Resources\Category1\SomeModel`

You will load it like this:

`Resources.Load("Category1\SomeModel")`

This means that you may get undefined behavior if you have different resources with the same name inside different Resources folders. This only works for assets inside Resources folders, as they are treated differently during build and packaging.

About the non-generic `Load`, I mean you should do it like this:

```
var myResource = Resources.Load("SomePath");
var myGameObject = myResource as GameObject;
```

This way, you can step through your code and see what's inside `myResource`. This is to make sure that you're passing the correct path. If `myResource` is not null, you can see what type of asset it is. Maybe you're loading an audio clip instead of the prefab you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! The VSTS indeed shows null object value for Resources.Load method on doing something like 'var slotally = Resources.Load(...) as GameObject'. Not sure why or how to fix it. What do you mean by non-generic Resources.Load? Also unity manual (https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.Load.html) says you must have a "Resources" folder.

Comment: Thank you! I will try that, and if works - I'll mark you up for karma :) Thanks again.

Comment: Works. Thank you so much!