# How to instantiate a prefab from the prefabs folder in runtime

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a string that has a prefab name, I want to instantiate a prefab with that name in the prefabs folder. Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to instantiate GameObject from prefab using Resources.Load?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54163372/how-to-instantiate-gameobject-from-prefab-using-resources-load)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is necessary to instantiate a prefab by its name, you can put said prefab into the Resource folder and use `Resources.Load` method:

```
// Instantiates a Prefab named "prefabName" located in any Resources folder in your project's Assets folder.
GameObject instance = Instantiate(Resources.Load("prefabName", typeof(GameObject))) as GameObject;
```

[Unity Manual on Resources.Load](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.Load.html)

Otherwise you can use SerializeField and choose the required prefab in the inspector

```
// Reference to the Prefab. Drag a Prefab into this field in the Inspector. 
[SerializeField] private GameObject myPrefab;

// This script will simply instantiate the Prefab when the game starts.
void Start()
{
    // Instantiate at position (0, 0, 0) and zero rotation.
    Instantiate(myPrefab, new Vector3(0, 0, 0), Quaternion.identity);
}
```

[Unity Manual on Instantiating Prefabs at run time](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/InstantiatingPrefabs.html)

Comment: Were is the resource folder?

Comment: It is necessary to create a new folder in the Assets and call it **Resources**. It is not created in the project by default. [Manual on Resources class](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.html)